# How to set tensorflow documentation as an external documentation in PyCharm?

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm

I can't figure out what is Tensorlow's API path pattern. I know it can be set in PyCharm in Settings -> Tools -> Python External Documentation, but I don't know how this Tensorflow API is structured; for example `tensorflow.contrib.data.python.ops.dataset_ops.Dataset` is under `https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/Dataset`.
Is there some convention regarding API paths?

Comment: The tags you have been using are not appropriate for this question. Please take the [tour], review [what are tags and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) and [edit] your post. Remember to at least read the mouseover on the tags you are using when asking a question. Thank you!

Comment: @Mogsdad I agree that `documentation` tag was used incorrectly and I apologize for that. I also removed `jetbrains` tag. I'm not sure whether I should leave `tensorflow` tag - question is not about code, but I couldn't find a better alternative.

Comment: Good question! If you come up with an answer please let as know. In general, I could figure it what should be the form of the url for Tensorflow but it would take me sometime and for now I have other priorities.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

Module Name: `tensorflow`

Path Pattern: `https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/{element.name}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is quite useful. The problem is it doesn't work for submodules. E.g. if I want to access `tf.data.Dataset` documentation I cannot use your pattern, but I can do something like that: `https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/{class.name}#{function.name}` but it's only for data submodule. How to put all things together?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a complete solution is not possible at the moment (v2019.2) but I ended up using this, which works well enough for me:

```
https://www.tensorflow.org/s/results?q={element.name}
```